# Where does this specific rhythm that everybody knows come from?

Tags: rhythm

Whenever a person gets the chance to hit a drum or make rhythmic noises in any other way, there is a high chance they will play this exact phrase:

[image: rhythm]

Example:

I have heard this countless times on many different occasions but so far couldn't figure out where exactly it comes from. Googling this is quite hard so maybe someone here can identify this.

Comment: Despite the fact that this is a duplicate, I think the rythm is not notated correctly in this question (sooos)

Comment: My bad, I think the rythm is right. In the duplicate question the fourth note of the second bar is a quaver note with a quaver rest. You have used a crotchet. Since this rythm does not have any duration of notes, I think one should use staccato points (this way both versions would sound the same).